# Android Studio generated Navigation Drawer's Header

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I've generated a navigation drawer using Android Studio by New -> Activity -> Navigation Drawer Activity. As a recent feature of Android Studio I didn't find enough examples through Google to access `TextView` in the header. I want to dynamically change the header title.

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
TextView tv = (TextView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.tvNavHeader);
```

In onCreate does not help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NavigationView` has a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226) in v23.1.0. You can't access to the views contained in the `HeaderView` in `onCreate` method.

A workaround is to inflate the `HeaderView` and add it programatically in the `onCreate` method like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_view, null);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(header);

        TextView tv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvNavHeader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer need to inflate the `HeaderView` anymore.

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

This works for one header. If you have several, just browse the [google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226) provided by Mattia.